# an Object's super class accessibilty

Tags: java, class, super

In Java, if I want to reach a method which exists in the ancestor classes of a random object, can I do this?

```java
someObject.Super.theMethodOfSuperClass();
```

For instance:

```java
public class A {
    public int getOne() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b = new B();
        b.super.getOne(); // This..works?
    }
}
```

Will the last line work?

P.S. I know without `super` (`b.getOne()`) works properly, I just want to understand the *Object.SuperClasses.Methods* thing..

Comment: You are asking or telling?

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: @Devavrata asking,FatalError JAVA

Comment: compiler error? IDE showing error ? what is the error?

Comment: i'm just asking if this supposed to work or not, and if not, why!
honestly I tried it my self, and the compilation error I get is :
 "b cannot resolved to a type"
and since the error isn't talking directly about the super thing, i'm not sure the compilation error casued because of the .super - so that i'm asking..

Comment: You tell us; easy enough to discover. You get the message because `b` isn't a type. Why is because this isn't how Java works.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2

Comment: @DaveNewton b is a type -_-, as you see above I did define b!

Answer (score 0):

Just skip `super()` and use `b.getOne()`. `getOne()` from A will be used!

Comment: I know, I just wrote you a quick example, the point isn't making the code work, and super, does not just belong to constructors, you can do super.getOne(); for instance, and that will work properly!

Answer (score 0):

no need to do b.super

methods in parent class are simply there

http://ideone.com/lyoSf3

```
b.getOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

The child class inherits the methods of the parent class. You can do something like this:

```
child.parentFunction();
```

There is no need for "super" in this case.

If you want to use super, that would be when you override the method in the child class but want to use the implementation from the parent class, like below.

```
class Parent{
    public int doStuff(){
        //parent code
    }
}
//child class
class Child{
    public int doStuff(){
        super.doStuff();
        //child code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `super` keyword with an object of subclass. It can be use inside body of any method of class. You can refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html for `super` keyword.

Similarly if you want to access it you can do it directly or `override that method.

```
class A
{
   public int getOne()
   {
      return 1;
   }
}
class B extends A
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       B b = new B();
       b.getOne(); 
   }
}
```

or another way :-

```
class A
{
   public int getOne()
   {
      return 1;
   }
}
class B extends A
{
   int getOne()
   {
       int i=super.getOne();   //here you can use super keyword
       //some work here
       return i;    // return what you need
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       B b = new B();
       b.getOne(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:* No you cannot reference the `super` class using the **.** operator from a subclass.

*Long one:* If you want to access an instance method from a super `class`, that implicitely means that you want to access a method that is already an instance method of your `class` (unless that method is marked to be **invisile** for classes' suptypes thus marked with either of the following access levels `private` or `default`).

That being said, you can access the method by calling its signature:

```java
public class A {
  public int getOne() {
    return 1;
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public int getOneFromSuperClass() {
    return getOne(); // here you are calling the method #getOne from superclass A
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
    b.getOneFromSuperClass();
  }
}
```

You can even, refer to the method with the `super` keyword if this method is already overriden in your subclass:

```java
public class A {
  public int getOne() {
    return 1;
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public int getOne() {
    return 2; // You catch it, this method returns 2 not like it seems to be doing
  }
  public int getOneFromSuperClass() {
    return super.getOne(); // Yes we can call the super getOne method to get the correct item
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.getOneFromSuperClass()); This will print 1 not 2
  }
}
```

You can even call the `super#getOne` method using an `B` reference since this method is inhereted from the superclass:

```java
public class A {
  public int getOne() {
    return 1;
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
    b.getOne();
  }
}
```

Notice that a refence to `B` class has been used to call a method defined in the `A` class, simply because this method is inhereted and then becomes an instance method of `B` as it was defined there.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but my question is, is
b.super.getOne() works or not!

Comment: I have exposed the multiple faces of the subject, assuming you have already figured out that it won't work on your own and you came looking for explanations not a yes/no answer.